# Custom URL for each user in PHP

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

Is it possible to have a website where each user gets their own URL like:
www.thewebsite.com/myusername

I want each user site to be the same, the only reason the name matters is if a person visiting the site signs up, they get their own custom url, but the person they signed up under is kept track of as their "Parent".

So if I go to www.thewebsite.com/phil and sign up as David, then my site becomes www.thewebsite.com/david but Phil is kept track of in my user record. (i.e. is there a way for me to know which url they visited the site under)

So, really that's 2 questions:

1) How do I make custom urls per user
2) How do I know which url a new user visited from

I'm pretty brand new to PHP so keep that in mind.

Comment: Am gave an excellent answer below, only I realized it might not be the answer I'm looking for.
What I want is for my url to be www.domain.com/user when someone sends that link in an email, but when it comes to my site, there is no www.domain.com/user directory.  My system would recognize that directory as a username and continue from there.
Basically, I want any valid user to be able to give out a link pointing to www.domain.com/MYUSER without that physical directory existing on my site.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this using the apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Make a rewrite rule for something like:

```
^/users/($1)    /users.php?userid=$1
```

In user.php file read the userid parameter, and return the page corresponding to given user.

As for racking from which user someone registered/logged-in to your site, you can keep a session value, such as the referencing userid, and when the new user registers, write to your db who referred him to your site.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without access to mod_rewrite?
As far as the mod_rewrite thing goes, I'm guessing that the URL just shows to the user as /users/myuser but still displays to my program as /users.php?userid=myuser
Is this correct?

Comment: "As far as the mod_rewrite thing goes, I'm guessing that the URL just shows to the user as /users/myuser but still displays to my program as /users.php?userid=myuser Is this correct?"

Yes, that's right.