# PHP Dynamic Profiles

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom URL for each user in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569733/custom-url-for-each-user-in-php)

I'm starting a new project building an online community. I would like to use a profile similar to Facebook in the way that each user has a unique url (ie http://www.facebook.com/username). I am familiar with using the $_GET function to get an ID from the URL but would much rather make the URLs short and memorable. As of today I noticed Facebook uses both /username and profile.php?id=1234 methods. Can anyone explain to me how this works? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a project of that size, it will involve authentication, collecting user input, and many other tasks that have already been completed by other programmers and tested for security. You should look into using a PHP framework such as CodeIgniter, Symphony, or CakePHP. This will make your life 10000000x easier in the long run.

As for your question, using mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file will do the trick of making the url look nice.

Comment: Thanks. Any further info on the .htaccess mod_rewrite?