# How to have detect/implement parameter passing like domain.com/parameters without '?' or any carrier variable like name=aksd

Tags: php

How to do that? Is it possible to do it without a framework? I'm using php.

Comment: Can you give example. Do you mean like domain.com/name/aksd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569733/custom-url-for-each-user-in-php has a similar question answered. This might help you out.

Comment: Take an example of about.me/some.name . I don't want further branching of sub directories after the domain name like domain.com/name/xyz. It should be direct like facebook urls or about.me urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation

Make a rule something like,

```
name\.($1)    webservice.php?name=$1
```

In webservice.php read the name parameter, and use it as you want.